# how to find nearest values both lower and upper in php?

Tags: php, arrays

How to find nearest values both lower and upper in array of objects in php?

```
    /* Code to find closest Start */
       $closest = array(); // Array to store closest of each set
       $diff = array();    //Array to store diffs to calculate the closest
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        // I am using DIAxRPM as key like 500x1400 for the first set
        $idx = "{$value->FAN_DIA}x{$value->FAN_RPM}";
        $tdiff[$idx] = abs(($value->STATIC_PRESSURE - $sp));
        //echo  $tdiff[$idx]." " ;
        if (!isset($diff[$idx]) || (isset($diff[$idx]) && $tdiff[$idx]<$diff[$idx] ) ){

            $closest[$idx] = $value->STATIC_PRESSURE;

            $diff[$idx] = $tdiff[$idx];
            echo $diff[$idx]."";
        }
    }

    print_r($closest);
```

Output:

```
Array
    (
        [500x1400] => 19.85
        [600x2800] => 141.74
        [500x2800] => 91.10
        [500x1450] => 21.46
        [560x1450] => 28.88
        [560x2800] => 120.45
        [630x1460] => 39.61
        [710x1450] => 52.29
        [800x1450] => 68.89
        [900x1430] => 86.69
        [1000x1450] => 111.46
        [1120x1450] => 140.88
        [1250x1450] => 176.19
    )
```

here i get only closest but i want both lower and upper nearest value in array object..Please help i am in this problem from last 2 days..

this is my $array
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FAN_DIA] => 500
            [FAN_RPM] => 1400
            [FAN_CMH] => 1000
            [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
            [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 25.00
            [FAN_DETAIL_ID] => 66
            [BLADE_ANGLE_ID] => 1
            [LOWER_LIMIT] => 0
            [UPPER_LIMIT] => 4849
            [COFFSET_ID] => 1
            [outlet_velocity] => 1.4154281670205
            [velocity_pressure] => 0.12253436672753
            [total_eff] => 0.30392346451101
            [static_eff] => 0.30205922285853
            [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 19.85
            [BKW] => 0.179
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FAN_DIA] => 500
        [FAN_RPM] => 1400
        [FAN_CMH] => 1000
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 26.00
        [FAN_DETAIL_ID] => 66
        [BLADE_ANGLE_ID] => 2
        [LOWER_LIMIT] => 0
        [UPPER_LIMIT] => 5069
        [COFFSET_ID] => 2
        [outlet_velocity] => 1.4154281670205
        [velocity_pressure] => 0.12253436672753
        [total_eff] => 0.28229305022887
        [static_eff] => 0.28059050300543
        [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 20.19
        [BKW] => 0.196
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FAN_DIA] => 500
        [FAN_RPM] => 1400
        [FAN_CMH] => 1000
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 27.00
        [FAN_DETAIL_ID] => 66
        [BLADE_ANGLE_ID] => 3
        [LOWER_LIMIT] => 0
        [UPPER_LIMIT] => 5288
        [COFFSET_ID] => 3
        [outlet_velocity] => 1.4154281670205
        [velocity_pressure] => 0.12253436672753
        [total_eff] => 0.26792548210575
        [static_eff] => 0.26633643803054
        [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 20.54
        [BKW] => 0.21
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FAN_DIA] => 500
        [FAN_RPM] => 1400
        [FAN_CMH] => 1000
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 28.00
        [FAN_DETAIL_ID] => 66
        [BLADE_ANGLE_ID] => 4
        [LOWER_LIMIT] => 0
        [UPPER_LIMIT] => 5508
        [COFFSET_ID] => 4
        [outlet_velocity] => 1.4154281670205
        [velocity_pressure] => 0.12253436672753
        [total_eff] => 0.25302701773787
        [static_eff] => 0.25155047235825
        [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 20.88
        [BKW] => 0.226
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FAN_DIA] => 600
        [FAN_RPM] => 2800
        [FAN_CMH] => 1000
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 25.00
        [FAN_DETAIL_ID] => 68
        [BLADE_ANGLE_ID] => 1
        [LOWER_LIMIT] => 0
        [UPPER_LIMIT] => 4849
        [COFFSET_ID] => 1
        [outlet_velocity] => 0.98293622709759
        [velocity_pressure] => 0.05909257654684
        [total_eff] => 0.10373541003493
        [static_eff] => 0.10369217931877
        [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 141.74
        [BKW] => 3.72252672
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FAN_DIA] => 600
        [FAN_RPM] => 2800
        [FAN_CMH] => 1000
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 26.00
        [FAN_DETAIL_ID] => 68
        [BLADE_ANGLE_ID] => 2
        [LOWER_LIMIT] => 0
        [UPPER_LIMIT] => 5069
        [COFFSET_ID] => 2
        [outlet_velocity] => 0.98293622709759
        [velocity_pressure] => 0.05909257654684
        [total_eff] => 0.094872284113262
        [static_eff] => 0.094833230277887
        [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 143.49
        [BKW] => 4.12065792
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FAN_DIA] => 600
        [FAN_RPM] => 2800
        [FAN_CMH] => 1000
        [FAN_SERIES_NAME] => AFPV3G
        [BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE] => 27.00
        [FAN_DETAIL_ID] => 68
        [BLADE_ANGLE_ID] => 3
        [LOWER_LIMIT] => 0
        [UPPER_LIMIT] => 5288
        [COFFSET_ID] => 3
        [outlet_velocity] => 0.98293622709759
        [velocity_pressure] => 0.05909257654684
        [total_eff] => 0.088309379039201
        [static_eff] => 0.088273449510657
        [STATIC_PRESSURE] => 145.18
        [BKW] => 4.478976
    )
```

Comment: The closest keys or the closest values of the array?

Comment: the closest values of the array

Comment: @priyaa can you provide your DESIRED OUTPUT ?

Comment: Post your array format and values...

Comment: . Like see list first array dia 500,rpm 1500 and blade angle is 25.. second dia 500 rpm 1400 n angle is 26.. like that i hv 4 blade angle 25,26,27,28 for same dia and prm.. again for dia 550 rpm 2000 ihave 25,26,27,28 blade angle..

Comment: Please help me plase

Comment: i suggest don't build the first array like that, instead also create a multi dimensional array on the first array as well so that you can compare both arrays

Comment: i hv to display result in datatables so it should be in array of objects not i multidiemsional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly your answer but can you :

- Sort the array using k_sort
- Iterate over the array until you find a greater element, take the previous one.
- The 2 elements are the one you are searching for

Comment: . Like see list first array dia 500,rpm 1500 and blade angle is 25.. second dia 500 rpm 1400 n angle is 26.. like that i hv 4 blade angle 25,26,27,28 for same dia and prm.. again for dia 550 rpm 2000 ihave 25,26,27,28 blade angle..